# protobuf-net v3 with surrogate and inheritance hierarchies

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm struggling migrating from *protobuf-net* v2.4.6 to v3.0.100 (or any 3.0.x) in regards to an existing type hierarchy used as `ProtoContract`s with one of the subtypes requiring a surrogate due to one of its property being of type `object`.

With previous configuration in place, I get the following exception thrown on creating the runtime model:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Types with surrogates cannot be used in inheritance hierarchies'

**Hence, my question is how to properly deal with this scenario using protobuf-net 3.0.x?**

Here's my (over-)simplified repro of the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
        _ = model[typeof(Base)]; // <-- InvalidOperationException thrown here

        Base value = new Complex();
        var copy = model.DeepClone(value);
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Simple))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Complex))]
public abstract class Base
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Simple : Base
{
}

[ProtoContract(Surrogate = typeof(ComplexSurrogate))]
public class Complex : Base
{
}

[ProtoContract(Name = nameof(Complex))]
public class ComplexSurrogate
{
    [ProtoConverter]
    public static ComplexSurrogate Convert(Complex source) => new ComplexSurrogate();

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static Complex Convert(ComplexSurrogate source) => new Complex();
}
```

As a side note: When compiling *protobuf-net* from source with the above mentioned exception suppressed, I'm able to defined a surrogate for the `Base` class which seems to serve as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, that scenario isn't supported. While reworking the code for v3, some ambiguous outcomes/intents were found, and it needs work to go in and figure out what the correct outcomes are in each case, design how to achieve that, implement it, and test it. That time has not yet been found, so *right now* it is safer to prevent a configuration that could lead to big problems downstream, than to just shrug and assume that whatever happens is correct. It is on my list of things to do, but: ultimately this is a project that comes entirely out of my own spare time - it isn't sponsored or part of my paid work, so: it'll get there when it gets there.

Comment: I'm having trouble migrating from v2 to v3 for a similar issue. Are there any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error in protobuf v3, and I solved that with custom serializer.

My base class is

```cs
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(500, typeof(XXXRequest))]
    [ProtoInclude(501, typeof(XXXResponse))]
    // ...
    public class MessageBase
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        long ID { get; internal set; }

        
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        int ExecutionMilliseconds { get; set; }
    }
```

Its equivalent proto is

```proto
message Message {
  int64 ID = 1;
  int32 ExecutionMilliseconds = 3;
  oneof body {
      PredictBonusRequest XXXRequest = 500;
      PredictBonusResponse XXXResponse = 501;
      // ...
  }
}
```

I want to replace some types (e.g. `XXXResponse`) to use the contract-first class instead. This would allow us to migrate from code-first to contract-first smoothly.

For sub-types should be surrogated, we create custom serializer as below.

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Serializers;

using UnderlyingMessage = GeneratedProto.Contract.Message;
using UnderlyingResponse = GeneratedProto.Contract.XXXResponse;

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract(Serializer = typeof(XXXResponseSerializer))]
public class XXXResponse : MessageBase
{
    class XXXResponseSerializer : ISerializer<XXXResponse>
    {
        public SerializerFeatures Features => SerializerFeatures.CategoryMessage | SerializerFeatures.WireTypeString;

        public XXXResponse Read(ref ProtoReader.State state, XXXResponse value)
        {
            ISerializer<UnderlyingMessage> serializer = state.GetSerializer<UnderlyingMessage>();
            return serializer.Read(ref state, value);
        }

        public void Write(ref ProtoWriter.State state, XXXResponse value)
        {
            ISerializer<UnderlyingMessage> serializer = state.GetSerializer<UnderlyingMessage>();
            serializer.Write(ref state, value);
        }
    }

    private readonly UnderlyingResponse _resp;


    public XXXResponse() : this(new UnderlyingResponse() { })
    {
    }

    private XXXResponse(UnderlyingResponse msg)
    {
        _resp = msg;
    }

    public static implicit operator XXXResponse(UnderlyingMessage value)
    {
        if( value != null)
        {
            return new XXXResponse(value.XXXResponse)
            {
                ID = value.ID,
                ExecutionMilliseconds = value.ExecutionMilliseconds,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static implicit operator UnderlyingMessage(XXXResponse value)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            return new UnderlyingMessage()
            {
                ID = value.ID,
                ExecutionMilliseconds = value.ExecutionMilliseconds,
                XXXResponse = value._resp,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Transaction[] Transactions 
    { 
        get { return _resp.Transactions?.Select(t => (Transaction)t)?.ToArray(); } 
        set { _resp.Transactions = value?.Select(t => (BE.Data.Contract.Transaction)t)?.ToList(); } 
    }


    public long DomainID { get { return _resp.DomainID; } set { _resp.DomainID = value; } }


    public string UniversalID { get { return _resp.UniversalID; } set { _resp.UniversalID = value; } }


    public string ExtraData { get { return _resp.ExtraData; } set { _resp.ExtraData = value; } }


    // other proxied fields ...
}
```

The key is, when `ISerializer.Read` or `ISerializer.Write` is fired, the wire-format is from the scope of the entrie message, including all fields of base class, and current sub-type is in a field whose number is identified by `ProtoInclude`.

In our case this works. For other sub-types which we don't want surrogate at this moment, it still works as it did.